# Javascript Dbconnectivity

Tags: javascript

Can any tell me is there any way that we can pass values using javascript that would execute in manipulating data in DBase

Answer (score 2):

Use [**AJAX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really big security problem.

You would have to write the database password in plain text.

Thats why most developers use AJAX to call a server side script.

This script manipulates the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [SQL Anywhere](http://gofrom.us/FPJ) you can publish webservices on data base and use AJAX to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this without using ajax and accessing a server side script. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) offers a simple AJAX platform, and [PHP](http://www.php.net/) could be used for a back-end.

If you have any details about your server environment, I'm sure somebody here can help you out.